# What is the keyboard shortcut for commenting out lines for CSS in Aptana Studio?

Tags: aptana

What is the keyboard shortcut for commenting out lines for CSS in Aptana Studio?

Answer (score 3):

For Aptana Studio 3.x, the keybinding is technically M1+/ for toggle comments. That translates to Command+/ on Mac, Ctrl+/ on most other platforms. This command should work across any language.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it by pressing   ctrl + 7

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> works for me!!! (Windows 10 + CCS 7)

Answer (score 0):

I do really miss commenting through shortcut Aptana 3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> don't works on my installation (linux, 64). Could you pleas look how the shortcut is binded under Preferences/Keys, just search for 'Comment'.

On mines the action binded to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> says:

Command: Python toggle comment

Binding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

When: Pydev editor scope

Category: Pydev - Editor

Comment: I'm using 64bit Ubuntu 10.04 + Aptana 3.2.2 + Sun Java, and I can multi-line comment using CTRL-SHIFT-/ and single-line comment using CTRL-/

Answer (score 0):

CSS allows only multi-line comments. In Aptana 3 just select a region you would like to comment out and use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem : it seems to be the same shortkey for 2 differents commands.

So i did that in Aptana 3 :

1. commands > Source > Edit this bundle
2. It should show "Source" folder in your "Project Explorer" window
3. Open Source/commands/toggle_comment.rb
4. Line 4 :

   > cmd.key_binding = ["M1+/", "M1+7", "M1+M2+C"]
5. Replace 'M1+/' by 'M1+WhatKeyYouWant'.
   Make sure that the new M1+X doesn't already exist
6. By example, my own modified shortcut is :

   > cmd.key_binding = ["M1+<", "M1+7", "M1+M2+C"]
7. restart Aptana 3
8. Enjoy

Hope that will help